# Exe setup creating error when running from desktop short cut and without Administrator right

Tags: c#, .net, installation, exe

**Problem :**

Here problem is that when i run my project's `.exe file`from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Atoz\My Product Name`  as administrative right so on that time it is working fine there is no error. But when i run my project's `.exe file` from `desktop or start menu` without administrative right or with administrator right then i am getting error as below.

**Error :**

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Authentication.IsValidUser(String Login_Id, String Pwd) in c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CarServiceNew\CarServiceNew\Authentication.cs:line 29
   at CarServiceNew.Login.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CarServiceNew\CarServiceNew\Login.cs:line 25
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.PerformClick()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
```

I am not getting any idea about it. so if somebody have any suggestion or solution of this problem then it will be expectable. Thanks in advance.

**Note**

`Here i have tried to give support for framework 4 on windows 7 os` and this project has been made in framework 4.5

Comment: So what is/does the code around the indicated lines in the stack trace?

Comment: I trace it with my project but on that time i was not getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you havnt set up the executionlevel. Open your app.manifest and edit it.

The important snipped should look like that:

```
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" />
        // and so on... //
```

If UAC is turned on, it should tell you on app-start that this tool requires admin-privilegs.

**Edit:**
Oh... I guess I missunderstood your question. You also get the error from desktop even if starting as admin right???